# Print the data from Nested ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a result which is returned in the form of `Arraylist` of arraylist of arraylist of string. I need to dump the data/object from the list to an external file.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>
```

Comment: Did you even attempt anything!? If so, show us your code and where exactly are you facing a problem.

Comment: please show what you tried

Answer (score 2):

```
for (ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list1 : myReturnedResult)
    for (ArrayList<String> list2 : list1)
        for (String s : list2)
            fout.println(s);
```

This should do it as long as you've managed to create a file to write to (`fout`).